# how to get rid of 16.04 repository configured on my 22.04 system?

Tags: linux, upgrade, repository

when i add `sudo apt update` to my terminal i got a warning which is related to having xenial (16.04 repository) on my 22.04 system. i add `find /etc/apt -type f -exec grep xenial {} +` command and i'll add the output below which shows that i have xenial (16.04 repository), and to remove it i have opened `'/etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-source-repositories.list'` using nano cli editor and gedit text editor there is no lines referring to xenial, is there another way to remove it ?

**1. sudo apt update warnings**

```
W: http://dl.openfoam.org/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu-stable/dists/jammy/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
```

**2. `find /etc/apt -type f -exec grep xenial {} +` output**

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-source-repositories.list.save:deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-source-repositories.list.save:deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-source-repositories.list.save:deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-source-repositories.list:deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-source-repositories.list:# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-source-repositories.list:deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
```

Comment: `there is no lines referring to xenial` ... clearly there are 3 as you can see in the output (the last 3 lines of your `find`)

Comment: noo i mean when i open to edit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-source-repositories.list and remove the lines referring to xenial i cannot find any.

Comment: no, they are there, you've shown that in your output. you must be doing something wrong

Comment: thank youuu... i repeated it and i was able to remove them, i don't know why they didn't show for me at the first time

Comment: @JaromandaX but why i still have them when i add `find /etc/apt -type f -exec grep xenial {} +` although i open the source list and remove the lines shown related to xenial **note that the warnings regarded it, in the output of `sudo apt update` are not found any more**

Comment: perhaps it's finding the entries in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-source-repositories.list.save` ... which isn't used for `apt` since it's not a `.list` file

Comment: @JaromandaX okay thankss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the 16.04 repository from your 22.04 system by editing the **software sources list**. First, open the sources list with a text editor:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then, locate the lines containing references to the 16.04 repository, and delete them. When finished, save the file and exit the editor.

Once the repository has been removed, you should update the package list to ensure that the system is aware of the change:

```
sudo apt update
```

This will update the system with the latest package information, removing any references to the 16.04 repository.